# Injecting inline styles from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner making a "To Do List". My main problem at the moment is that when i add a `p` element with my button and click it the styles are applied on the second click. Any clue how to solve this bug? I tried to use an event listener instead of onclick but I'm getting the same result.

```js
console.log("connected");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  //adauga butonul / add the button
  document.getElementById("adauga").onclick = function() {
    console.log("connected");

    let usr = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    console.log(usr);
    //take userinput

    //removes from text input the text
    document.getElementById("user_input").value = "";

    //create the p element
    let task = document.createElement("p");
    document.body.append(task);
    task.classList.add("text-style");
    document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(task); //il adauga in container
    task.innerHTML = usr;
    //

    //onclick styles
    task.onclick = function() {
      task.style.color
      if (task.style.color === "black") {
        task.style.color = "red";
        task.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      } else {
        task.style.color = "black";
        task.style.textDecoration = "none";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #003060;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #68BBE3;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.titlu {
  text-align: center;
}

.tlinie {
  color: 10px solid black;
  width: 798px;
}

.text-frame {
  display: flex;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 780px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-style {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  width: 780px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.scrie {
  width: 710px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.buton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="titlu">TO DO LIST APP</h1>
  <hr class="tlinie">
  <div class="text-frame">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type.." class="scrie" id="user_input">
    <button class="buton" id="adauga">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Default inline styles don't exist, add the style attribute, or rather toggle the class name, and include suitable classes to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `if (task.style.color)` condition is returning `undefined` on the first click, so the state does not match what you expect.

To fix this you can instead toggle a class on the element when it's clicked.

In addition, you can tidy up the code by removing some redundant expressions, better naming of variables, and reducing the number of DOM operations by selecting the elements outside of the click handler.

With all those updates made, try this:

```js
const userInput = document.querySelector('#user_input');
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("adauga").addEventListener('click', function() {
    const usr = userInput.value;
    userInput.value = "";

    //create the p element
    const task = document.createElement("p");
    task.classList.add("text-style");
    task.innerHTML = usr;

    task.addEventListener('click', function() {
      task.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    
    container.appendChild(task);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #003060;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #68BBE3;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.titlu {
  text-align: center;
}

.tlinie {
  color: 10px solid black;
  width: 798px;
}

.text-frame {
  display: flex;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 380px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-style {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  width: 780px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.text-style.active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.scrie {
  width: 710px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.buton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr class="tlinie">
  <div class="text-frame">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type.." class="scrie" id="user_input">
    <button class="buton" id="adauga">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I reduced the width of the container in the CSS only so that the example fits better in to the SO snippet.